# TeamCity not picking up VCS changes after server rollback

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

We are using TeamCity 9.0.0. The server got corrupted for reasons not relevant to this discussion, so I had to rollback to a stable snapshot (we use Amazon AWS snapshots), which was roughly 12 hours old. I lost some of the builds that happened during those 12 hours but that's ok.

The restore seemed to work, but now the VCS Triggers are not happening. The VCS root is from TFS 2013.

I tried checkin in new changes and builds still don't trigger. I tried running the build manually and it doesn't pick up the latest changes.
It looks like something got out of sync when I restored the snapshot.

Thoughts?

--------Update 1 -------

I looked at the history and I see several builds triggering after I rolled back my server so I think that is not related. I tried creating a new VCS root and removing the existing one. I checked in a change and the build triggered fine. I tried a second check in and this time the build didn't trigger. It's almost like it misses some changesets.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning Server cache at `<TeamCity Data Directory>/system/caches`. If even that doesn't work try deleting and re-creating the VCS.